# Return indexes of greatest values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to have a function that returns the greatest value of an array.
I am aware of that this question was asked many times, but what in a case when in an array we have more then one the highest value? 
Lets assume that our array looks like this:

```
var arr = [1,10,2,10];
```

Function:

```
arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, arr) );
```

will return only index 1, but I would like to get 1 and 3.

What is the shortest and most efficient way to do so.

Comment: You will have to write the method your own I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const largest = Math.max(...arr);
arr.reduce((indexes, n, index) => {
  return indexes.concat(n === largest ? [index] : []);
}, []);
```

Or, if ES5 is your cup of tea:

```
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
arr.reduce(function(indexes, n, index) {
  return indexes.concat(n === largest ? [index] : []);
}, []);
```

Or, if generic functions are your thing:

```
function findAllIndexes(arr, val) {
  return arr.reduce((indexes, element, index) => {
    if(element === val) {
      return indexes.concat([element]);
    } else {
      return indexes;
    }
  }, []);
}

findAllIndexes(arr, Math.max(..arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

The "manual" way:

```
    var getIndicesOfHighest = function(arrIn) {
        var indices = [];
        var highest = arrIn[0];
        for (var el=1; el<arrIn.length; el++) {
            if(arrIn[el] > highest) {
                highest = arrIn[el];
                indices = [];
                indices.push(el);
            } else if ( arrIn[el] == highest) {
                indices.push(el);
            }
       }
       return indices;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
var arr = [1,10,2,10],
    indices = [],
    highest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
arr.forEach(function(val, index){
    if (val === highest) indices.push(index);
});
console.log(indices.join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
var arr = [1,10,2,10];
var ind = [];
var highValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
arr.map(function(x, i) {
    if (x == highValue) {
    ind.push(i)
  }
});
console.log(ind);//output is [1,3]
```

Comment: This is O(N^2), calculate max first and then iterate through array, which is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var highestIndexes = [];
$.each(arr,function(index,item){
   item== Math.max.apply(Math, arr) ? highestIndexes.push(index) : $.noop();
});
console.log(highestIndexes);
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Just for the completeness, a proposal with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var arr = [1, 10, 2, 10],
    max = arr.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (!i || a > aa[r[0]]) {
            return [i];
        }
        if (a === aa[r[0]]) {
            r.push(i);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(max, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore/lodash and _.reduce you could write a method to find all indexes based on whatever condition you pass in.

Like:

```
function findAllIndexes(_arr, condition) {
  return _.reduce(_arr, function(arr, o, index) {
    if(condition(o, _arr)) arr.push(index);
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

console.log(findAllIndexes(nums, function(o, arr){
  return o === Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
}));
```

This same method can be used with array of Object litetals with whatever condition you give it

Like

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'active': true },
  { 'user': 'barney',    'active': false },
  { 'user': 'bob', 'active': false }
];

console.log(findAllIndexes(nums, function(o, arr){
  return o.user == 'barney' && o.active == false;     
}));
```

http://jsbin.com/jadesayicu/edit?html,js,console,output